# In Blender 2.80, when i try to bake a fluid simulation using flip fluids, it gives me the error 'Cannot find fluid engine library: libblpyfluid.dll'

Tags: fluid-simulation

When I bake a fluid simulation in FLIP Fluids(which a built from [source](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids) using Visual Studio 16 2019),it shows the error

> Cannot find fluid engine library: libblpyfluid.dll.

I really want to use flip fluids and mantaflow seems to be less powerful.

On https://blog.dodslaser.se/Building-and-Installing-the-Blender-FLIP-Fluids-Addon-from-Source/ I did try to change

`if system == "Windows":
    libname = "libblpyfluid.dll"` to

`if system == "Windows":
    libname = "blpyfluid.dll"`)

Specs:
OS:Windows 10 insider build 18956
Blender version: blender 2.80
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4610M CPU @ 3.00GHz
GPU: using integrated graphics with PHDGD Skylake v2.9 custom driver(i tried it without it and same error)

wanting t build it to see if any limitatios are not in the build one(RLGUY could you update your answer for this?)

Comment: I found a video explaining it! yay(RLGUY you still helped alot ;) ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44n3z3g9sVc&t=3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [note on the the GitHub repository](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids#source-code-dependencies), the Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler is not officially supported:

> WARNING: Compilation using MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler) is experimental and not officially supported. Building with MSVC may result in errors and performance issues.

When building the FLIP Fluids addon for Windows, the MinGW compiler should be used to avoid potential errors and to ensure the simulator runs correctly.

Comment: RLguy you still here? got ploblem when compiling in Mingw makeflies https://imgur.com/a/1DYY40Y

Comment: At first glace it looks like your development environment might not be set up correctly with the installed MinGW compiler and GNU Make utility, or that CMake is unable to locate your MinGW installation or GNU Make installation. This seems like more of a programming related question rather than a Blender question and you might have better luck at finding a solution on the programming related stack exchanges.

Comment: ok yeah i did not install it properly and i also had to add C:\MinGW\bin to my Path(not PATH) system variables. but i still got the error,should i also build with Open_CL?(console error here:https://pastebin.com/F3NqFSkF)

Comment: You had mentioned in the question that you modified the source to look for ```blpyfluid.dll``` instead of ```libblpyfluid.dll```. I would suggest reverting back to the original source. When the addon is built in a supported compiler, it will generate the .dll as ```libblpyfluid.dll```.

Comment: changed, still error but its cannot find libbpyfluid.dll, should i try building from console/cmd?(pastebin https://pastebin.com/PpWVLT9S)

Comment: If the fluid engine library cannot be found, that could indicate that the compilation of the engine did not complete. I would check for any errors during the build/compile stage. When the addon compiles completely, the file should be located at ```bl_flip_fluids/flip_fluids_addon/pyfluid/lib/libblpyfluid.dll```. I have not used the CMake gui application, so I am not sure if there are differences. We use the commands in the [repository build instructions](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids#building).

Comment: built it from cmd using mingw.no file in the lib folder

Comment: also, should i try MSYS and see if that helps?

Comment: I haven't used MSYS, so I'm not sure. At the end of compiling, the location of the .dll should be displayed: https://i.imgur.com/zWi5qus.jpg

Comment: when i type "make" and hit tab since im not finnilliar with that command to tell me nothings and gives me an error, using powershell, any ideas?(on windows 10 insider build 18956)(also this is my first time building something so i'm probably doing something wrong)

Comment: just read the help by typing cmake --help and tried mingw32-make and problem solved! took way to long.wish i read the docs earlier.Thanks for the help! EDIT:well when ran got new error... https://imgur.com/a/GQMU6tl

Comment: also just tried install mingw-w64 dono how to use but when i did the same command hoping for a defference same error

Comment: RLGUY could you see whats wrong? not that good with building from source :)

Comment: Hi, it sounds like CMake might still be selecting the 32-bit compiler. You might need to look up how to force CMake to use the 64-bit compiler on one of the programming exchanges. Sometimes resolving build errors can be difficult without some programming experience.